# a method has two almost identical if-conditions; is it possible to optimize the code

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, optimization

I have a `Windows Form` project which use `MDI`. I have a method that is responsible for saving the data from any editable forms that are open and this method is called for different events. But I also use it on the parent's form `before close` event where I need to check for all opened MDIchilds, if there are editable forms amongst them and if there is, to ask for save. Other than that I only care if the `ActiveMdiChild` is editable and ask for save only for it.

Here is the method that do this job:

```
protected void AskForSaveBeforeClose(object sender)
{
    //Get the active child
    BaseForm activeChild = this.ActiveMdiChild as BaseForm;
    //Casting to MainForm return null if the sender is child form
    Form mainForm =  sender as MainForm;
    //If the before close event comes from the parent loop all forms 
    if (mainForm != null)
           {
        foreach (BaseForm f in MdiChildren)
        {
            if (f.isEditable == true)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("To Do Do You Want To Save from MainForm " + f.Text, "Status",
                         MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                         MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    f.Save();
                }
            }
        }

           }
    //if the event is not from the parent's before close just ask for the active child 
    else if (mainForm == null && activeChild != null)
    {
        if (activeChild.isEditable == true)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("To Do Do You Want To Save from AC ", "Status",
                      MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                      MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                activeChild.Save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`BaseForm` is a form that everyone inherits even the parent form. For now I have accomplished to put the code in one method so now I call only this method, but what bothers me is that the two parts are almost identical but still I can't figure out how I can optimize the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also create collection, which you loop through.

```
protected void AskForSaveBeforeClose(object sender) {   
    //Get the active child
    BaseForm activeChild = this.ActiveMdiChild as BaseForm;
    //Casting to MainForm return null if the sender is child form
    Form mainForm =  sender as MainForm;

    //Create collection to loop through
    List<BaseForm> formsToCheck = new List<BaseForm>();
    if (mainForm != null && MdiChildren != null && MdiChildren.Any())
        formsToCheck.AddRange(MdiChildren);
    if (mainForm == null && activeChild != null)
        formsToCheck.Add(activeChild);

    // Only check editable forms
    formsToCheck = formsToCheck.Where(f => f.IsEditable).ToList();

    // Loop through forms
    foreach (BaseForm f in formsToCheck) {
        var fromText = "MainForm " + f.Text;
        if (f == activeChild)
            fromText = "AC";
        if (MessageBox.Show("To Do Do You Want To Save from " + fromText, "Status",
                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                 MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes) {
            f.Save();
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, gonna try this one!

Answer (score 3):

By using functions. Put those codes into a function, parametrize as needed.

Scheme:

```
void askToSave (Baseform f) {
    if (f.isEditable == true)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("To Do Do You Want To Save from MainForm " + f.Text, "Status",
                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                 MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            f.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

and you can rid the nesting of the if-statements:

```
    if (f.isEditable == true && 
        MessageBox.Show("To Do Do You Want To Save from MainForm " + f.Text, ....
```

This works because `&&` (like `||`) are short-circuiting operators, which means that as soon as the condition is falsified, from left-to-right, the rest of the operands are not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect your valid forms into a List, where T can be an interface implementing all the stuff you need for your business logic (maybe a List itself is enough). Elements (forms) should be added to this list, then in a subsequent cycle you can iterate through this list, showing message boxes and saving if needed.
At worst, your list will contain just the main form, as far as I can understand.